# Return 404 if pagination is out of range

Tags: category, 404

Currently, when I navigate to a page in a category that is beyond the range of the products (say page 6 on a category containing 200 products with 50 products per page), the page returns a 200 http code and shows the products from the last page (in this example page 4).

Anybody know how to fix this? I'm currently on 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration to fix this.  You would have to make a modification to the controller (or possibly through an observer).  If you are rewriting the controller to make the change, you can detect if you are out of range and call:

```
$this->norouteAction()
```